# How do I check for a specific string to get from a Firebase Database to filter what data is received?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Explaining my code below, I'm trying to see if the userType is equals to admin and set it to either user or admin. Unfortunately my if condition is not working and I have no idea how to go into the else statement. Currently I'm logged into the dummy user email.

[image: Here is an image of my database structure.]

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => { 
    console.log(user.email);
    console.log(user.uid);
    var standardUserType = "user";
    //firebase().database().ref('adminUIDs').equalTo(user.uid);
    //firebase().database().ref().child('accounts').child(user.uid).orderByChild('userType').equalTo(standardUserType).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    firebase().database().ref('adminUIDs').equalTo(user.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists() && user) {
            console.log("[admin] user data has been pushed to database");
            firebase.database().ref().child('accounts').child(user.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                userId: user.uid,
                userType: "admin"
            })
        }else{
            console.log("[user] user data has been pushed to database");
            firebase.database().ref().child('accounts').child(user.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                userId: user.uid,
                userType: "user"
            })
        }
        });
    console.log(checkUserType);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to look up a node whose **key** you know. For that you don't need a query, but can use a direct lookup (which also has the advantage that it happens at a fixed speed, not depending on the number of child nodes under `adminUIDs`).

The code for it is:

```
firebase().database().ref('adminUIDs').child(user.uid).on("value", function(snapshot) {
    firebase.database().ref().child('accounts').child(user.uid).set({
        email: user.email,
        userId: user.uid,
        userType: snapshot.exists() ? "admin" : "user"
    })
});
```

I also simplified your `if` condition into a ternary expression, to reduce the amount of duplicate code.

Comment: Strangely enough your code doesn't work. For some reason it can't read the first thing! I fixed it afterwards though to fit with my code. Thank you for the answer! Also, I'm curious, but is there a way to check for a newly registered user so I can persist a rule that only adminUIDs can write? I had to set my rules to both true and I wanted to know if there was a way to add exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately my if condition is not working and I have no idea how to go into the else statement

This means that `(snapshot.exists() && user)` is always evaluating to true, when in fact you don't want it to (at least once, I assume).

Whenever logging in, `onAuthStateChanged` will be triggered with a non-null user object. But it is the `snapshot.exists()` part which probably needs to be changed to more accurately reflect what you're trying to do.

The docs for [snapshot.exists](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#exists) say "Returns true if this DataSnapshot contains any data. It is slightly more efficient than using snapshot.val() !== null".

Looking at the image from your database structure, it appears that even when `isAdmin` is false, that path, `adminUIDs/{theUserID}` will still have *some non-null value*, specifically, `{isAdmin: false}`.

So changing `(snapshot.exists() && user)` to `(snapshot.exists() && user && snapshot.val().isAdmin)` could do the trick.